# How do you search arXiv by sub-subject?

Tags: arxiv

How do you search arXiv by sub-subject?

For example, underneath the subject Computer Science, you have the subject 'Artificial Intelligence', and under the subject Quantitative Finance, you have the subject 'Computational Finance'.

How do I search for papers specifically within these subjects? Clicking on the subjects only brings up recent submissions, but I want all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Advanced Search](https://arxiv.org/search/advanced) for this, specifically the 'All fields' option in the dropdown menu. Set that value to the abbreviation/code for the subcategory, e.g. cs.ai or q-fin.CP for your examples. These seem unique enough to not pick up many false positives, and will (unless you specify otherwise) also pick up crosslisted papers. Refine the query as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Example: History and Overview is on the main ArXiv page in the Mathematics category.  Click on that [History and Overview link] and you get recent results. But at the top is the abbreviation/code for the subcategory [in this case it is arXiv > math > math.HO]. So, math.HO is the phrase to enter in the search field. The same strategy can be used to find the abbreviation/code for any subcategory. At that point the user can just tailor the display to display 25 or 50 results per page and and presumably use other common arXiv filters such as the advanced search features of related to date,.... The same strategy can be used for any subcategory such as "High Energy Physics" Experiment which is "hep-ex" which would be entered into the search field.

This note involves English so "Mathematics" and "History and Overview" are the English link encoding of the arXiv subjects / topics / categories. The following should work for whatever language is being displayed if other languages are available.